# Xamarin C#: ImageButton, deselecting a button upon selecting another one

Tags: c#, xamarin

I'm building a game, one of the 'mechanics' is selecting a tool by clicking on one of the three ImageButtons (representing a Drill, a Hammer and a Brush).

I want to mark the clicked button selected but only until I switch tools by selecting a second one. Is there any clean way of unselecting/selecting buttons?

Current code:

```
        if (drillbutton.Selected)
        {
            brushbutton.Selected = false;
            hammerbutton.Selected = false;
        }
        else if(hammerbutton.Selected)
        {
            drillbutton.Selected = false;
            brushbutton.Selected = false;
        }
        else if(brushbutton.Selected)
        {
            drillbutton.Selected = false;
            hammerbutton.Selected = false;
        }
```

There must be an easier way... Right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could assign the same click handler to every button, like this:

```
private void SelectButton(object sender, EventArgs args) {

  // you will have to have an IEnumerable that contains your set of buttons
  foreach(var b in buttons) {
    if (b == (Button)selected) b.Selected = true else b.Selected = false;
  }
}
```